# Mathematical formulas for easing functions (ElasticEase, CircleEase, BounceEase, BackEase, PowerEase)?

Tags: wpf, math

I can figure out the formulas for all polynomial functions, 
like e.g. the formula for QuinticEase is:

> (x - 1) ^ 5 + 1

But what are the mathematical formulas for ElasticEase, CircleEase, BounceEase, BackEase, or PowerEase?

They should all be in the range 0..1

Comment: To use easing functions in code, they are shifted to the range of t=0 to t=1. (x-1)^5 does the x-axis shift, +1 does the y-axis shift.

Comment: The input that the EasingFunction uses is always normalized and hence between 0 and 1.

Comment: Ok, sorry for the confusion. The above formula is actually for direct quintic ease-out computation. x^5 is used for ease-in and to compute ease-out, the range is shifted. The code which i took from WPF's EasingFunctionBase is: `1.0 - this.EaseInCore(1.0 - normalizedTime)` which is equivalent to the above formula when applied to quintic ease.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most formulas can be found [on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee308751.aspx), if it's not right there check the respective ease's subsite.

For the more complex functions where the reference does not name the function you can use a decompiler like [ILSpy](http://wiki.sharpdevelop.net/ilspy.ashx) to look at the code of the `EaseInCore` methods on the respective classes.

Comment: There are only images. Can't find any formulas for the easing functions in a range from 0..1 there.

Comment: Not true, on the [CircleEase](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.circleease.aspx) site the formula `f(t) = 1 - Sqrt(1-t^2)` is noted for example.

Comment: oh, didn't see that. thx! Unfortunately, I'm especially interested in the formulas for ElasticEase and BounceEase. Just those formulas aren't there.

Comment: Thanks! Great page. It even has a graphical previewer.

Answer (score 7):

see this JavaScript project http://jstween.blogspot.com, at the bottom you'll find the Tween.js file that has needed formulas inside.

Comment: Cool! Thank you! If I could accept a second answer, it would be yours.

Answer (score 2):

I found nice site containing implementation in different languages: [Robert Penner's Easing Functions](http://www.robertpenner.com/easing/)

For example, Elastic easing C++ code:

```
float Elastic::easeIn (float t,float b , float c, float d) {
    if (t==0) return b;  if ((t/=d)==1) return b+c;  
    float p=d*.3f;
    float a=c; 
    float s=p/4;
    float postFix =a*pow(2,10*(t-=1)); // this is a fix, again, with post-increment operators
    return -(postFix * sin((t*d-s)*(2*PI)/p )) + b;
}

float Elastic::easeOut(float t,float b , float c, float d) {
    if (t==0) return b;  if ((t/=d)==1) return b+c;  
    float p=d*.3f;
    float a=c; 
    float s=p/4;
    return (a*pow(2,-10*t) * sin( (t*d-s)*(2*PI)/p ) + c + b);  
}

float Elastic::easeInOut(float t,float b , float c, float d) {
    if (t==0) return b;  if ((t/=d/2)==2) return b+c; 
    float p=d*(.3f*1.5f);
    float a=c; 
    float s=p/4;

    if (t < 1) {
        float postFix =a*pow(2,10*(t-=1)); // postIncrement is evil
        return -.5f*(postFix* sin( (t*d-s)*(2*PI)/p )) + b;
    } 
    float postFix =  a*pow(2,-10*(t-=1)); // postIncrement is evil
    return postFix * sin( (t*d-s)*(2*PI)/p )*.5f + c + b;
}
```